# Effect of output capacitance

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

Is there more information about the effect of an output capacitor on a circuit? That is, does an output capacitor with (parallel) resistive load contribute any [poles or zeroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole%E2%80%93zero_plot), and how can I determine the location of said poles and zeroes?

I assume there is probably some relationship similar to an RC filter where ω = 1/RC, but in my case, I do not have a series resistor. Furthermore, is there any contribution by the [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) of the capacitor itself?

Comment: Please provide a simplified schematic.  An output capacitor is usually in series with the load but you mention a parallel resistive load.  Some clarification would be helpful!

Comment: my problem would be very similar to this

[link](http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/images/pwrsupsm.gif), with a resistive load being connected across "output".  I would like to know the effects of that "smoothing" capacitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The analysis of the effect of a capacitor placed across the output terminals, in parallel with the resistive load, can be done by considering the load to be the parallel combination of the capacitor and load resistor.

Without the "output capacitor", your circuit has an output impedance, \$Z_O \$ and an open-circuit phasor output voltage, \$V_{oc} \$.  Your load is an impedance, \$Z_L\$.

The phasor load voltage is then:

\$V_l = V_{oc} \dfrac{Z_L}{Z_L + Z_O}\$

Now, let's assume that the output impedance is real:  \$Z_O = R_O \$

If the "load" is a capacitor in parallel with a resistor,

\$Z_L = \dfrac{R_L}{1 + j \omega R_L C_O}\$

Then:

\$V_l = V_{oc} \dfrac{R_L}{R_L + R_O}\dfrac{1}{1 + j \omega (R_L||R_O)C_O} \$

So, yes there is a pole due to the parallel capacitor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This looks like a very good method, but the only problem I see is that it may be very difficult to predict the output impedance for real power electronic converters.  Is there some normal assumption that can be made for that value? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The above is linear AC analysis.  For non-linear elements, you must linearize the elements about their operating point just like SPICE does for AC analysis.